# How can I change text on my SearchWP search results page, as this is not an editable page in Wordpress?

Tags: php, search, html

I just want to change the text "Search results for:" to something else e.g. "All results for:"

The class is .page-title. I can't find this anywhere and I cant edit the page html as this page is generated when a search is performed. I basically can't find where the HTML for this is stored.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you mean the SearchWP plugin, you'll have to ask the plugin's support team about this. Third-partly plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: You'd probably need to add a custom template to your theme that takes over for the default Search template.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.